# How to display message on the unit test result window for successful unit tests? c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I gave written a data-driven unit test in C# and the unit test uses MS Visual Studio unit test framework. For unsuccessful unit tests, exception would be thrown and a message would be shown in the unit test result windows. I hope to display some message for successful unit tests and the messages should be shown in the unit test output window. How to do it? I have tried Console.WriteLine("Message") but it doesn't work as I wish. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why? What are you looking to achieve with what should grow into an endless list of successful tests? The problem with including success messages is that they would soon drown out any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use Debug.WriteLine() to write to the output window.

Place this at the end of your test:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test Finished!");
```

Comment: your suggestion doesn't work like what I want. That would output the message after I click on the Output link under the test result. I want it to be shown directly like the way the message in "throw new Exception("Failed.")" is shown.

Comment: I believe writing to the Test Explorer window is not possible, your best option would be to use the output window as it is intended for scenarios like yours.

Comment: Why exactly do you want text output for a passing unit test?

Comment: My unit tests are a bit dynamic so I want to know the content and context of the particular unit test. I have just written the unit test and I wish to see the output so that I could ensure the correctness of the unit test I have written. I am debugging the unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, VS2019, one can output text to the test output window like this.

For this code, you'll need a dependency on [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform/) and works best in conjunction with [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting?view=mstest-net-1.2.0).

The test output is accessible from the Test Explorer side-bar, as a link, only after the test was executed. Clicking on that link will open the full test output window.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace YourNamespace.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class SomeTestClassName
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void Test1()
        {
            ConsoleOutput.Instance.WriteLine("+++ This test line ends up in the test output +++", OutputLevel.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What dependency does this need? `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools` is not standard available. NuGet package?

Comment: Try the nuget package from  nuget.org repository.